# Django Interrupted system call when sending email

Tags: django

Sometimes, when submitting a form (pretty much any form on my site that sends me an email), I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 603, in starttls
   (resp, reply) = self.docmd("STARTTLS")

 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 378, in docmd
   return self.getreply()

 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/smtplib.py", line 352, in getreply
   line = self.file.readline()

 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/socket.py", line 381, in readline
   data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)

error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

My code is sending email via gmail. I am also using django contact-form which does the same thing.

The problem doesn't always happen. It seems very random. At one point today it got so bad that it displayed the error every time I submitted a form.

Restarting apache fixes the problem for one submission and then it does it again.

I have checked the RAM and there is plenty available (about 350MB available).

Can someone lead me in the right direction? What does this error mean? What can I do to prevent this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it got to do with a bad network connection to the smtp server.
Looks like it gets interrupted while trying to read the reply from the server?

Comment: Is there anything I can do that would prevent the errors from happening? Something like try: this and if it fails, try again. Then maybe after 3 attempts, just skip the email sending? If so, what kind of exception would I catch for this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may want to try increasing the socket [timeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

As for fixing this, you may not have a stable connection to GMail's server and there may not be a way around this.

It looks as if the `EINTR` signal is being thrown before the `recv` call gets any data back.

Answer (score 0):

The recv call used by smtplib is being interrupted by a signal before any data was read.  Per the read(2) manpage, POSIX allows a read() that is interrupted after reading some data to return -1 (with errno set to EINTR) or to return the number of bytes already read.

In Python, EINTR raises an IOError: "[Errno 4] Interrupted system call" (EINTR == 4).

An example of how EINTR is properly handled is subprocess.communicate().  See an excellent post here:
http://znasibov.info/blog/post/inside-python-subprocess-communication.html

However, in Python 2.5, socket.readline() does not properly handle EINTR.  See:
http://bugs.python.org/issue1628205: socket.readline() interface doesn't handle EINTR properly